# Add a link to each tag’s Documentation in users’ profiles

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, documentation

Currently, users’ profiles have a Top Tags section:
[image: Top Tags]

I’m proposing that a “Documentation” link be added to each tag:
[image: Documentation links]

This increases discoverability of the Documentation feature, as well as showcasing that  user’s contributions to Docs.

Answer (score 7):

I wouldn't do that, since it's making the profile page look clogged without. Instead, I'd add the link to the docs in that window which appears when you hover the tag, either from the profile page or the questions page.

> [image]

This way the user also won't see the excess links for the tags they are probably not interested in.

Comment: Here’s a better image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Dmgin.png

Comment: @JF *Better*? Not enough freehand! ;)

Comment: No — I did want to include how it would really look (of course, SO could do redesigns with freehand **everything**, but that’s unlikely).

Comment: @JF Oh, don't be dull, [just kidding](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775) :D

Comment: Yeah. **:** **)**